# Get the absolute path of current running program in kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

In order to retrieve file permissions of the running program, I need to do a `kstat` on the program currently running. Then I need to get the absolute path of the ELF image loaded.

Is that possible? `current->comm` only records the program name without path.

Or what other ways to do it?

Comment: Seems to me like trying to implement policy inside the Linux kernel code. [Never a good idea](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/8110/print). What is it that you plan to achieve? Why the need to know the permission of an executable inside the Linux-kernel code?

Answer (score 2):

You can `readlink(2)` with the path to `/proc/self/exe`, which in your case would be a link to the ELF. Metaexample using `readlink(1)`:

```
$ readlink /proc/self/exe
/bin/readlink
```

Linux-only as far as I know.

Comment: I believe @warl0ck wants to be able to do this from kernel code.

Answer (score 0):

The `proc` filesystem returns this information in `/proc/<pid>/exe`, so you need to do something similar.

`proc` gets the path of a process in the function `proc_exe_link` in `fs/proc/base.c`. This function is adapted from `proc_exe_link`:

```
char *get_current_proc_path(char *buf, int buflen)
{
    struct file *exe_file;
    char *result = ERR_PTR(-ENOENT);
    struct mm_struct *mm;

    mm = get_task_mm(current);
    if (!mm) {
        goto out;
    }
    down_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
    exe_file = mm->exe_file;
    if (exe_file) {
        get_file(exe_file);
        path_get(&exe_file->f_path);
    }
    up_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
    mmput(mm);
    if (exe_file) {
        result = d_path(&exe_file->f_path, buf, buflen);
        path_put(&exe_file->f_path);
        fput(exe_file);
    }

out:
    return result;
}
```

This will put the path somewhere in `buf` (not necessarily the beginning of the buffer), and return a pointer to the path. On error, it will return an `ERR_PTR`, so check that the pointer is valid with `IS_ERR`.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean getcwd()? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html

```
#include <unistd.h>
char * getcwd(char * buf, size_t size);
```

------------------EDIT----------------------

you wanna check another running program's path, you can find it in /proc/$PID/exe:

```
ll /proc/$PID/exe
```

or

```
ll /proc/$PID | grep exe
```

or

```
readlink /proc/$PID/exe
```

Comment: That's a libc function (not even a system call!), and it doesn't have anything to do with the executable path.

Comment: @duskwuff Ohhh. The question was about watch another program. I have changed my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
Table 1-5: Kernel info in /proc         .............................................................................. 
File        Content                                           
apm         Advanced power management info                    
buddyinfo   Kernel memory allocator information (see text)  (2.5)
bus         Directory containing bus specific information     
**cmdline**     Kernel command line
```

Ex.

```
[root@localhost ~]# more /proc/364/cmdline
/usr/sbin/smbd
[root@localhost ~]# more /proc/364/common
/proc/364/common: No such file or directory
[root@localhost ~]# more /proc/364/comm
smbd
[root@localhost ~]#
```