# How can I identify which program a tcp packet came from in a linux kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, tcp, linux-kernel

I'm currently working on an assignment in which I need to write a linux firewall extension.

A bit of context:

My kernel module will maintain a list of "rules". A rule is just a port number with a path to an executable file. A rule indicates that the program is allowed to make outgoing connections on the corresponding port.

A connection by program A on port X should only be terminated if there are rules for port X and program A is not one of them. So if a port has no rules set, anyone can communicate on the port.

I know how to analyze the TCP packet headers and extract the source port. My problem is, how can I tell which program created this packet?

Here is some example code my lecturer gave me, although I'm not sure how it helps. I've removed parts that aren't relevant for clarity.

```
int init_module(void)
{
    struct path path;
    pid_t mod_pid;
    struct dentry *procDentry;
    struct dentry *parent;

    char cmdlineFile[BUFFERSIZE];
    int res;

    mod_pid = current->pid;
    snprintf (cmdlineFile, BUFFERSIZE, "/proc/%d/exe", mod_pid); 
    res = kern_path (cmdlineFile, LOOKUP_FOLLOW, &path);
    if (res) {
      return -EFAULT;
    }

    procDentry = path.dentry;
    parent = procDentry->d_parent;
    printk (KERN_INFO "The name is %s\n", procDentry->d_name.name);
    printk (KERN_INFO "The name of the parent is %s\n", parent->d_name.name);
    path_put(&path);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't tell from the packet.  You would need to monitor the system calls within the kernel to identify which process initiated the call.

Comment: Recent question, which is quite similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47634064/finding-name-of-executable-sending-packet-in-a-netfilter-hook. Are you aware of it? How does your question differ from it?